# Prove that if $0\le p_n \lt 1$ and $S:=\sum p_n \lt 1$, then $\Pi (1-p_n) \ge 1-S$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, inequality, infinite-product

Prove that if $0\le p_n \lt 1$ and $S:=\sum p_n \lt 1$, then $\Pi (1-p_n) \ge 1-S$.

I'm having real trouble proving this inequality. I'd greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: Finite or infinite number of $p_n$'s?

Comment: Infinite number

Comment: Hint: Prove by induction on $n\geqslant1$ (or even $n\geqslant0$) that $$\prod_{k=1}^n(1-p_k)\geqslant1-\sum_{k=1}^np_k.$$